# Raise a Particular Error in t-SQL with RAISERROR

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, raiserror

I have a view that has an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger (in SQL Server 2005). When the user inserts into the view, they are in fact making inserts and updates to a number of tables. The view is sufficiently complex that it cannot have an index, so is unfortunately unconstrained.

The view is being inserted into from C# using code that would be problematic to change. This code catches primary and unique key violations using the following:

```
try
{
    ... // Insert into view
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 2627 || ex.Number == 2601) // Primary key exception, unique constraint violation
    {
        ... // Report the duplicate entry to the user
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

So my question is: can I use `RAISERROR` within my trigger to create an exception with number 2627 or 2601?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You'll have to wait for [THROW in the next release](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/22/sql-server-v-next-denali-exploring-throw) (maybe)

You can only throw errors that you have put into sys.messages (50000+), or with text that gives 50000. Or embed it in the text and change your c#. You can't throw errors less than 50000

If the view is so complex that you can't use DRI, then it is *too* complex. Also, you'll have concurrency issues: overlapping calls **will** break your "uniqueness" at some point when you roll your own.

Comment: Thanks, fair enough. My understanding is that schema-bound views can only be indexed in SQL Server 2005 if they have no left joins, no unions, and no sub-queries. In my opinion, these do not necessarily make a view too complex.

Comment: @Paul: they do because maintaining an indexed view would require a lot of processing with these constructs. See "Why can't I use OUTER JOIN in an indexed view?" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I meant too complex to be useful as a view, not too complex for SQL Server to maintain an index upon. In my case, the view does not have outer joins, but has a subquery so that I can restrict based on the result of the ROW_NUMBER() function.

Comment: @Paul: ROW_NUMBER() would require the whole indexed view to be recalculated (change of place/removal in ORDER BY, change of partition etc). There are good reasons for the limits on indexed views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can actually `RAISE` a genuine primary key violation. Though you can `RAISE` your own error with your own message and then `catch` that. This will also allow you to distinguish between a genuine primary key violation and your own custom violations.

Perhaps the crudest way to accomplish this would be...

SQL Code (in `TRIGGER` definition maybe)...

```
RAISERROR('Custom View Violation',16,1);
```

C#...

```
try 
{
    //execute SP / Insert etc...
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Split('\r')[0] == "Custom View Violation")
    {
        //deal with your exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...that may well be what I need to do if raising a primary key error cannot be done. Alternatively, I could cause a genuine primary key violation by inserting two identical values into a temporary table with a primary key...both seem a little hacky though :-S

Comment: @Paul yeah they are a little hacky - though I would say that the method in my post is less hacky than the double `INSERT` you propose. I'm also sure there is a better way of `RAISE` ing the error and catching your specific exception so probably best to read-up on the ins-and-outs of `RAISERROR`.

Comment: Yes, agreed.   [and some more characters]